# How to retrieve and append data using the same web api get request in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, http-get

Here I am using "$http.get" request to retrieve data from Web API in Angular.js.

An API URL has a parameter call "pageNo=" and it's require to add a digit at the end of that parameter to retrieve a data of respective page number to maintain heavy request loads, each page has 10 list of records.

I took a scope variable ($scope.pageCount) and pass it with the URL, it's working fine and able to retrieve 10 list of records at once.

Now I am suppose to get the rest of data on scroll down (like using infinite-scroll) and append it with the existing list of data.

Is it possible or any way to retrieve more data from the same request?
I have added 'infinite-scroll' to the application and getting an alert on scroll down.

Following is the current working function.

```
app.controller('SpotLightCtrl', function ($scope, $http, shareEventID) {

    $scope.pageCount = 1;
    $http.get("https://stg.myapi.svc/pageNo="+$scope.pageCount+)
      .then(function (response) {
          $scope.data = response.data;

          $scope.loadMore = function () {
              alert('Load more records');
          };

      });

});
```

And the HTML code:

```
<div class="content-block spotlight-listing" ng-controller="SpotLightCtrl" infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='1'>
    <h1>Spotlight</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="event in data.eventList" class="deals-block">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 img-style">
            <a href="/SpotLight-Detail"><img ng-src="{{event.eventPosterImage}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please share if any details is not clear, Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: There may have been a problem copying you JS over to SO, I suggest you check and fix it.

Comment: Oh, let me check

Comment: right George, have updated the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the http call in a function and call the function with the pagecount.

```
app.controller('SpotLightCtrl', function ($scope, $http, shareEventID) {

 $scope.pageCount = 1;
 $scope.data = [];
 function getData() {
    $http.get("https://stg.myapi.svc/pageNo=" + $scope.pageCount)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.data = $scope.data.concat(response.data);
        });
 }

 $scope.loadMore = function () {
    console.log('Loading more records');
    ++$scope.pageCount; //page count is incremented by 1, so
    getData();
 };

 getData();
});
```

when the loadMore function is called pagecount is incremented by one and the next records are appended to the $scope.data

Comment: Appreciated.. Thanks.